# When calling D3D's CREATEDEVICE from inside DLLMAIN in VC++, it creates a deadlock(loaderlock?). Is there a way to overcome this? End goal inside

Tags: c++, deadlock, optimus, dllmain, loaderlock

A while back I made a post regarding creating a dll, for the purpose of injection, that will cause the host application to trigger an Nvidia Optimus laptop to "awaken" the dGpu. This being necessary because of the pathetic system nvidia created here which results in MANY applications not recognizing the presence of the power dGpu, and instead using the integrated intel gpu. (Specifically some video processing apps which take hours longer using Intel's than it would Nvidia's). That post was [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/found-a-way-to-make-any-program-run-with-the-discrete-nvidia-dgpu-but-i-need-a).

Suffice to say, I moved to work in Antarctica and gave up on the project. I just picked it back up years later and decided to learn (enough) C++ to program it here. I have created the DLL, and if I place the DX code in a function, then call that function from a host "caller" program.. IT WORKS!!! However, if I put that code in the DLLMAIN, and then simply load that dll from my "caller" program (without actually calling a specific function)... the procedure executes!!! However, when it gets to the part of the code where CREATEDEVICE is run, it crashes. I have since learned this is due to an issue called deadlock, or loaderlock.. i'm not sure which. I understand the concept, but don't have anywhere NEAR the C++ understanding to develop a workaround.

So basically.. can I run my procedure in DLLMAIN using some workaround? Maybe spawning an independent thread somehow (so DLLMAIN can finish executing to it's return?) Thanks for any info. I'll include the vcproject source code here.. but it's a Frankenstein of things I found online.. so don't look for elegance- I know next to nothing about C++ programming! http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07876333208461296171

Answer (score 0):

The loader lock is a lock which is per-process and owned just after you call LoadLibrary, until just before the LoadLibrary returns.  It is intended to ensure the process correctly accounts for the loaded DLLs and their order.

There is very little code which can be added in DllMain which doesn't run the risk of a fail, as any Windows call which may cause IPC can fall fowl of the loader-lock.

If you can create a thread from outside the process, or create a second function you can call directly,  then this will be a better solution